# Finding an optimized path using set of data

Tags: machine-learning, path-finding, robotics

I want to replicate what the user does in my program. If I can keep a record the motor states through out the time the user drives, and do this 3 times what is the best way to find and optimal path using that type of data. Or is there anyway to easily replicate what the user does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a CSTheory type of question.  Pathfinding and strategy selection is an incredibly deep topic that has more to do with algorithms than programming.  It has an intersection with system design in that memory and compute constraints may rule out certain algorithms.

There's a good discussion of pathfinding there, which you may find helpful:
https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/11855/how-do-the-state-of-the-art-pathfinding-algorithms-for-changing-graphs-d-d-l

At a system design level it would probably be more effective to capture user input directly if you want to replicate that.  If your goal is to replicate behavior, then capturing the motor states as you suggest may actually work better.